# inserting comma separated to output

Tags: php, cakephp

I am struggling to insert comma separated after each item, if more than one item.

I have all values as they should, only missing the comma.

$result = $html->link($tags[$cv], array('controller'=>'postTags','action' => 'view', $post_tags[$ck]), array('title'=>'Vis artikler under '.$tags[$cv],'escape' => false));
    echo $result = substr($result,0,-2);

This output correct links *without comma*: test1test2test3 if multiple => should be; test1, test2, test3

Also if only 1 item => output should be test1 (no comma).

So, code as is, does output correct links, but no comma! I am not sure how to proceed, any suggestions?

Tried implode (full-code using cake 1.3);

```
$ci = 0;
    $post_tags = explode(",", $content['Post']['tag_id']);
        if(!empty($post_tags)){
            foreach($post_tags as $ck => $cv) { 
                if(isset($tags[$cv])){
                    $ci = $ci+1;
                    $result = $html->link($tags[$cv], array('controller'=>'postTags','action' => 'view', $post_tags[$ck]), array('title'=>'Vis artikler under '.$tags[$cv],'escape' => false));
                    //pr($result);
                    $commaSeparated = implode(',',$result);
                    echo $commaSeparated;
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
```

Give me error.. ;//

pr($post_tags);

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

pr($tags);

```
Array
(
    [1] => Tag1
    [2] => Tag2
    [3] => Tag3
    [4] => Tag4
)
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
// get only the tags assigned to the post
$postTagKeys = array_flip($post_tags);
$tags = array_intersect_key($tags, $postTagKeys);

// ok lets make the links:
$tagLinks = array();

foreach($tags as $tagId => $tagName) {
   $tagLinks[] = $html->link(
       $tagName,
       array('controller'=>'postTags','action' => 'view', $tagId),
       array('title'=>'Vis artikler under '.$tagName,'escape' => false)

   );
}

//$tagLinks is now an array of html <a> tags linking to individual tags
// so to ouput the list we do

echo implode(', ', $tagLinks);
```

---

If you have the categories as an array just use implode:

```
$cats = array('test1','test2','test3');
$cats2 = array('test1');

echo implode(', ',$cats);
echo implode(', ',$cats2);
```

So using your example code:

```
         foreach($post_tags as $ck => $cv) { 
            if(isset($tags[$cv])){
                $ci = $ci+1;
                $taglist = implode(', ', $tags[$cv]);
                $result = $html->link($taglist, array(
                  'controller'=>'postTags',
                  'action' => 'view', 
                  $post_tags[$ck]  // are you sure you want to pass the array here and not just the array key?
                ), array(
                  'title'=>'Vis artikler under '.$taglist,
                  'escape' => false)
                );

                echo $result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats because result is a string it needs to be an array.

Comment: yepp.. I figured... Any suggestions? See main topic for whole code.

Comment: see my update... if the example i posted doesnt work can you post an example of the structure of `$post_tags`... Also it looks to me like there might be issues with your arguments to your link helper... what framework/app are you using?

Comment: I tried it,, not working.. I am using cakephp. As I mentioned in my main topic, It output correct categories and link as it should, I am only missing the comma => testCat1, testCat2 ++   It output correct links like this: testCat1testCat2 +++

Comment: Right, but the proper way to do this is to mainpulate the categories before you use them in the link. So you need to work with them before you compile them into the string `testCat1testCat2` while they are still and array or recordset, not trying to do string replacement after the fact. So ill ask again, where do you get the `$post_tags` data from and what does that array look like currently? it may be as simple as adding a `getFormattedTags` method to your `Post` model.

Comment: Okei,, here goes => $posts_tags are from posts table tag_id, example: 1,3,4  and $tags array are from tags table (all tags). So I am trying to compare the two, and list the selected post.tag_id => with link to tag view page. Something like this; Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8452/discussion-between-prodigitalson-and-tom)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) which does exactly what you need:

> Join array elements with a string

use it likle this:

```
$commaSeparated = implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: @Tom whatdo you mean"not working"? if you do `print_r($result)` what do youget?

Comment: It is not an array,, not sure how to proceed,, see main topic for full code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$result = $html->link($tags[$cv] . ((count($tags) > 1 && $ci > 0 && count($tags) != $ci) ? ', ' : ''), array(
                              'controller' => 'postTags',
                              'action' => 'view',
                              $post_tags[$ck]
                          ), array(
                              'title' => 'Vis artikler under ' . $tags[$cv],
                              'escape' => false
                          )
                      );
```

Btw just use `$ci++;` instead of `$ci = $ci+1;`.